# Timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: asp.net, connection, max, connection-pooling

I am getting following error after hosting the application:

**Error Page    : http://********.in/Presentation Layer/NewQuotation.aspx**

Error Message : Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

StackTrace    : at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetNewOpenConnection()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetOpenConnection(Boolean disposeInnerConnection)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteReader(DbCommand command)
   at DataLayer.Quotation_DL.insertQuoteproduct(QuotationProductCombination _objQP) in F:\gayathri reddy\Enq Quote\06-01-2015\DataLayer\Quotation_DL.cs:line 430
   at BusinessLayer.Quotation_BL.insertQuoteproduct(QuotationProductCombination _objQpc) in F:\gayathri reddy\Enq Quote\06-01-2015\BusinessLayer\Quotation_BL.cs:line 88
   at EngQuote.Presentation_Layer.NewQuotation.Quotationsave(Int32 status, String oper) in F:\gayathri reddy\Enq Quote\06-01-2015\EngQuote\Presentation Layer\NewQuotation.aspx.cs:line 3711

But while running the code in local Visual Studio 2010 there is no issues, when i host it in **server or local machine IIS or Shared hosting server** on that time only we are facing this issue

I have tried  following all these steps but have not got any improvement

1).Opened and closed the connection in every DL function

2).Increased the command time out in this way 
                 DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Procedurename");
                cmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
                SqlDataReader sdata = (SqlDataReader)db.ExecuteReader(cmd);

3). Increased connection time out in web config

4). Increased executionTimeout in web config

5). Increased shutdown time out

6). Changed debug=false

but no use,connection time out problem still exists for long processes 
Please suggest any solution other than above options
Expecting a good solution for this issue from u peoples
thanks in advance....

Comment: Is the connection `static`? Do you use the `using`-statement to ensure that it gets closed as soon as possible? Show some code.

Comment: DbConnection con = sqldb.CreateConnection();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
               int CusIdent = Convert.ToInt32(sqldb.ExecuteScalar("spInsertCustomerCompanyGroup", objCustGrp.GroupName, objCustGrp.CreatedBy, objCustGrp.CreatedDate));
               return CusIdent;  
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

Comment: hi, i am not using (using statement) check following                       DbConnection con = sqldb.CreateConnection();                   try {                                                  con.Open(); int CusIdent = Convert.ToInt32(sqldb.ExecuteScalar("spInsertCustomerCompanyGroup", objCustGrp.GroupName, objCustGrp.CreatedBy, objCustGrp.CreatedDate));                                   return CusIdent;                                                 }                                                                 finally { con.Close(); }

Answer (score 3):

I guess connection between IIS and SQL Server was too slow to serve a connection. Just make sure the max connection limit is not reached. You can confirm by executing below select statement.

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
```

You can try increasing pool size in connection string. But this will have some downside. Below is the sample connection string with increased pool size.
`server=localhost;database=dbname;uid=username;pwd=paswrd;Max Pool Size=200;`

Comment: thank u for ur reply friend, i have tried this query in sql but shows 
NumberOfConnections
1  and i have increased max pool size to 300